# Why are compiled bundled files different with same version of webpack and sourcecode?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Have an issue with webpack(or maybe something else not really sure) where on one machine when we run webpack the code works but on another machine code doesnt work.

The source code, config files, webpack versions are all the same on both machines.  We compared the resulting bundled file from each machine and they are totally different. What could we check to see why the two machines produce two different bundled files?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: have you checked the versions of all of the dependencies? (only thing I can think of)

Comment: Are they different operating systems / file systems?

Comment: How is the project moved from the working machine to the non-working machine? Copy the entire directory including node_modules?

Comment: Thanks guys for the responses.  My feeling is some versions are not matching but not sure what to check, not very experienced with webpack here.  We have a repository and we cloned from the exact same branch so everything should be the same.  Same OS, file system.

Comment: Please indicate what _code doesn't work_ means. Does the build process halt? What errors do you see. Also is the node_modules folder in your repository?  (it should not be).

Comment: We can disregard what I said about code doesnt work, it just means our webpage doesnt work with one version of the bundled file but works with the other version.  What I need to figure out is how to get my bundled file (the one that is not working ) to look exactly the same as the one that is working.

Comment: webpack has a [cli](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli) as well that is not dependent on the repo you're cloning. versioning there might be impacting the results